# Scala Array.view memory usage

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and have been trying some LeetCode problems with it, but I'm having trouble with the memory limit being exceeded. One problem I have tried goes like this:

> A swap is defined as taking two distinct positions in an array and swapping the values in them.
>
> A circular array is defined as an array where we consider the first element and the last element to be adjacent.
>
> Given a binary circular array nums, return the minimum number of swaps required to group all 1's present in the array together at any location.

and my attempted solution looks like

```
object Solution {
    def minSwaps(nums: Array[Int]): Int = {
        val count = nums.count(_==1)
        if (count == 0) return 0
        val circular = nums.view ++ nums.view
        circular.sliding(count).map(_.count(_==0)).min
    }
}
```

however, when I submit it, I'm hit with *Memory Limit Exceeded* for one of the test case where `nums` is very large.

My understanding is that, because I'm using `.view`, I shouldn't be allocating over `O(1)` memory. Is that understanding incorrect? To be clear, I realise this is the most time efficient way of solving this, but I didn't expect it to be memory inefficient.

The version used is Scala 2.13.7, in case that makes a difference.

#### Update

I did some inspection of the types and it seems circular is only a `View` unless I replace `++` with `concat` which makes it `IndexedSeqView`, why is that, I thought `++` was just an alias for `concat`?

If I make the above change, and replace `circular.sliding(count)` with `(0 to circular.size - count).view.map(i => circular.slice(i, i + count))` it "succeeds" in hitting the time limit instead, so I think `sliding` might not be optimised for `IndexedSeqView`.

Comment: Don't use **leetcode** to learn **Scala**, as you saw they force you to write mutable solutions and use `Array` - You will mostly never do that in the language.

Comment: So far I've only come across one problem where you had to use mutation, I'm sure there's more, but it appears most can be solved with idiomatic Scala.